# Resume game cocos2d

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocos2d-iphone

I used he code below to handle pause and resume buttons in my game

To Pause:

```
-(void)pauseTapped{
...    
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] pauseBackgroundMusic];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
...
}
```

To Resume:

```
-(void)resumeGame: (id)sender {
...
    [self removeChild:pauseMenu cleanup:YES];

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] resumeBackgroundMusic];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
...
}
```

The problem is if the used click pause then enterBackground (click Home button) mode 
when he returns, the game automatically resume and the pause menu still exist

Any idea will be great

**UPDATE:**

the AppDelegate code:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}

- (void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
}

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [[director openGLView] removeFromSuperview];

    [viewController release];

    [window release];

    [director end]; 
}

- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setNextDeltaTimeZero:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: post ur appdelegate code

Comment: let me know is this works or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a property to your app delegate that will keep track if pause was caused by user tapping pause button or automatically.

Inside YourAppDelegate.h:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL userPaused;
```

And inside YourAppDelegate.h:

```
@synthesize userPaused;
```

Then inside your scene's pause method, add:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.userPaused = YES;
```

And inside your scene's resume method, add:

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.userPaused = NO;
```

Now you can edit your app delegate's -applicationWillResignActive: method to only resume if userPaused is not set to YES.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    if (!self.userPaused) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    }
}
```