# How to remain pause after resume the game from background in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, 2d-games

I have a toggle menu which toggle between the words "Pause" and "Resume" when it is pressed, which also pause and resume the whole game. This means when playing, the menu will be shown as "Pause" (tap here to pause), when pausing the menu will be shown as "Resume" (tap here to resume).

Here is the problem, if I tap the home button after I pause the game, then go back into it, it resumes itself and the pause menu is shown as "Resume". And this doesn't make sense to me. The best way I want is to pause the game whenever go into the background and resume from background. I look at the following methods, but they don't really work:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
}

-(void)applicationWillEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application{
}

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

I even just put CCLOG in all of those methods, but nothing has been called. Is there something I am need to put/declare before I use those methods?

Sorry, it is a bit too long to read. Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: You should consider marking your questions as correct as it encourages SO users to answer your questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538323/how-to-actually-pause-a-cocos2d-scheduled-selector

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but for my experience (not cocos2d), there's no additional implementation if want apply those methods.

perhaps, you should try look at this.

[link 1](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/16/topics/7598) & [link 2](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/7/topics/2919)

Comment: thank for the answer people i got this [link][1] 
and this link solved my issue thanks for the help by the way
[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214939/resume-game-cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
}
```

you need custom your cocos2d CCDIRECTOR class. And get now display layer. then active it pause or resume function. All this must need some protocol.

Answer (score 0):

These methods are invoked when the iOS forces your application in the background, or resumes execution of your application, ie they are signals you receive when an external event causes your application to go to background, or come back from it. You should not try to invoke them directly. There is no real relationship with a 'user created' menu like yours (like your Resume/Pause menu), unless you make the relationship explicit.

So , in the following method:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"<%@>:applicationWillResignActive - received signal, pausing sharedDirector.",[self class]);

    // here : place your code for forcing your menu in the 'Resume' state
    // i am assuming some kind of change in a button,  and
    // a state variable of your own that define and control
    // what it means to be 'paused' from your applications point of
    // view

    // then force the director to pause (animations, scheduling, touch, etc ...)

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
}
```

after, when the iOS hands you back control by placing your application in the forground as the running application:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"<%@>:applicationDidBecomeActive - received signal, resuming sharedDirector.",[self class]);

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
}
```

You dont really need to do anything fancy here other than restart the CCDirector, since your menu is in the 'Resume' state, garanteed. When user presses Resume, you will start your game again and put the menu in the 'Pause' state.

Comment: oups, just saw your comment saying you had solved your issue. As a side note, you should either accept an answer, of answer it yourself so you can accept your own answer. This way, the question will be marked as answered, and not attract further answers just as i did :)